# Casting an HTTP response from JSON to interface not behaving as expected

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http

I am making a get request to a server from an angular client. The service in which I am making the calls needs to return an observable with an array of objects. The problem is that typescript doesn't seem to allow me to cast the JSON to my interface.

This is the JSON object the server is sending as a response:

```
export interface Message {
    title: string;
    body: string;
}
```

This is the interface I want to cast the body to. There body should contain an array of these objects:

```
export interface ICommonGameCard {
    id: string;
    pov: POVType;
    title: string;
    image_pair?: ICommonImagePair;
    best_time_solo: number[];
    best_time_online: number[];
}

export enum POVType{Simple, Free};
```

This the the service making the requests:

```
public getGameCards(povType: POVType): Observable<ICommonGameCard[]> {
    return this.http.get<ICommonGameCard[]>(this.BASE_URL + this.GET_ALL_CARDS_URL)
        .pipe(
          map((res: Response) => return <ICommonGameCard>res.json().body),
          catchError(this.handleError<Message>("getUsernameValidation")),
      );
```

}

Obviously, this is not working. I am trying to cast the response's JSON to the message Interface, and then access the message's interface body where there is an array of ICommonGameCard.

I am getting this error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Response, ICommonGameCard>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<ICommonGameCard[], ICommonGameCard>'.
  Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'ICommonGameCard[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more. [2345]
```

What exactly is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Take a look at https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface Message {
    title: string;
    body: ICommonGameCard[];
}
```

```
public getGameCards(povType: POVType): Observable<ICommonGameCard[]> {
    return this.http.get<Message>(this.BASE_URL + this.GET_ALL_CARDS_URL)
        .pipe(
          map((message: Message) => message.body),
          catchError(this.handleError<Message>("getUsernameValidation"))
      );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but will this really work? The response should be the Message interface and the array of ICommonGameCard is in the "body" field of the message. From what I see from the code you shared, this would try to convert both the "title" and "body" fields to an array of ICommonGameCard, which would not work.